# set different zoom levels for localhost web-apps in google chrome

Tags: google-chrome

My dev machine has different web-apps running at localhost on a specific port, eg.:

- http://localhost:4451/
- http://localhost:8080/
- http://localhost/

When I set a zoom pref (ctrl+mouse scroll) in localhost:4451, google-chrome automatically applies this zoom level to all web-apps running at localhost. It would be really useful to me if chrome could remember the zoom level between each application.
Question: It's possible to change chrome default behavior and set a different zoom level per web-app considering the port number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem that zoom in and out in Chrome is being set for all tabs with the same domain. This was pointed out as an issue before, but was closed as "WontFix" by the Chronium development team as it is the intended behaviour (see [Link](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=390775)).

So a Chrome extension is in my understanding the only way to do it. There are several offering this functionality e.g.:

- The Per-Tab-Zoom Chrome extension (Windows only) [Link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/per-tab-zoom/dnhodapkogdjinogphlafimejpmahoam/related?hl=en)
- Single Tab-Zoom Chrome extension [Link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/single-tab-zoom/palhkglkelpleoalemmjdhbdckkikjmo/related?hl=en)
- ...

Comment: its a nice extensions, but not friendly for ubuntu os. It needs to install a local program to run which target windows machines.

Comment: @Mꜳltus I hope you will find the new edit of my answer useful - unfortunately I cannot comment on the quality of any of these extensions.